# Split string by tags into different variables

Tags: java, regex

I need to split a string containing parts with tags. For example:

```
String str = "This text is not highlighted <hlTag>but this is</hlTag> this"
           + " isn't again <hlTag>and this is</hlTag>";
```

The problem is that all parts should be saved into different variables (in this example I just print them out), so my parser should know, which parts were inside the tags and which not.

I already have solution and it works, but I use two regexes there for both cases and I think it can be simplified, so I ask your for help to do that.

**EDITED**

I realized that my solution is wrong — I loose the order of the parts and I need it to be respected. I need to parse the string once and save parts into different objects for tagged and nontagged parts, something like this — if highlighted, list.add(new HighlPart(text)), else list.add(new NonHighlPart(text)).

Can anybody help me with it?

```
String preTag = "<hlTag>";
String postTag = "</hlTag>";

Matcher insideTagsMatcher = Pattern.compile(preTag + "(.+?)" + postTag).matcher(str);
Matcher outsideTagsMatcher = Pattern.compile("^(.*?)" + preTag +
    "|" + postTag + "(.*?)" + preTag +
    "|" + "</hlTag>(.*?)$").matcher(str);

System.out.println("Highlighted:");
while (insideTagsMatcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(insideTagsMatcher.group(1));
}

System.out.println("\nNot highlighted:");
while (outsideTagsMatcher.find()) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= outsideTagsMatcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        // each pattern group returns two nulls except of string we need
        if (outsideTagsMatcher.group(i) != null)
            System.out.println(outsideTagsMatcher.group(i));
    }
}
```

The result is:

```
Highlighted:
but this is
and this is

Not highlighted:
This text is not highlighted
this isn't again
```

Comment: Regex is a lousy parser, except for very simple syntax. Use an actual parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cleaner and safer way would be use [Jsoup](https://jsoup.org/).

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.TextNode;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Document document = Jsoup.parse("This text is not highlighted <hlTag>but this is</hlTag> this isn't again <hlTag>and this is</hlTag>");

    List<String> highlighted = document.select("hlTag")
            .stream()
            .map(element -> element.html())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    List<String> nonHighlighted = document.body().childNodes().stream()
            .filter(node -> node instanceof TextNode)
            .map(node -> node.toString().replaceAll("\n",""))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    highlighted.forEach(System.out::println);
    nonHighlighted.forEach(System.out::println);
}
}
```

Output:

```
but this is
and this is
This text is not highlighted 
 this isn't again
```

**UPDATED** after changes in question:

The `List` keep the order of the inserted elements. You can't add different types of object to a List. If I understand correctly your new needs you can do something like:

```
List<Node> nodes = document.body().childNodes(); 
nodes.forEach(System.out::println);
```

nodes is a List of Node elements. Each Node (in that example) can be of a type `TextNode` or `Element`. In your example TextNode correspond to the content not wrapped in a tag when parsed from body and Element objects correspond to the content with tags. This way you will have a unique List with all element and you can difference between them using it's object type (`instanceof`).

You want to print the highlighted part? Then:

```
nodes.stream().filter(node -> node instanceof TextNode).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Want to print nonHighlighted parts? Then:

```
nodes.stream().filter(node -> node instanceof Element).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Thank you! One more question — can it be saved into one list with saving of order of the parts? I mean, if I have different objects for tagged and nontagged parts, could I parse it once and do something like this — if highlighted, list.add(new HighlPart(text)), else list.add(new NonHighlPart(text))?

Comment: if updated response, remember to accept the response if solves your problem ;)